# QTreeWidget snaps back when moving items

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

When I'm using a QTreeWidget (via qdesigner) with the dragDropMode set to InternalMove and then attempt to move one of the items, the scrollbar snaps back to the original position of the item I moved.  I would like the scrollbar to stay at the position the item was dropped.  Is there an easy way to do that? I adjusted the defaultDropAction, but to no avail.

Comment: provide  a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

```
class MyTree : public QTreeWidget
{
   Q_OBJECT
   public:
      MyTree(QWidget *parent = 0);
   signals:
      void verticalScrollBarValue(int val);
   protected slots:
      void setTreeVerticalScroll(int val);
   protected:
      void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);
};
```

```
MyTree::MyTree(QWidget *parent) : QTreeWidget(parent)
{
   connect(this, &MyTree::verticalScrollBarValue,
           this, &MyTree::setTreeVerticalScroll);
}

void MyTree::setTreeVerticalScroll(int val)
{
   verticalScrollbar()->setValue(val);
}

void MyTree::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
   int v = verticalScrollbar()->value();
   QTreeWidget::dropEvent(event);
   emit verticalScrollBarValue(v);
}
```

Disclaimer: There may be a typo in there somewhere, I can't copy directly from my work environment.